# PySceneDetector throws exception for basic function

Tags: python, opencv, debian

This is my original problem condensed into the bare minimum:

I created a Debian Google Cloud Compute Instance with Python 3 and pip. Then I installed PySceneDetect with dependencies like this:

```
pip3 install scenedetect[opencv,progress_bar]
```

Then I permanently and globally added the scenedetect directory to PATH by adding it to **/etc/profile**

Now, when I run scenedetect from the terminal, I get this error:

> scenedetect.video_manager.VideoOpenFailure: OpenCV VideoCapture object failed to return True when calling isOpened(
> ).

And then this one while handling the first one:

> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object

Here is a screenshot of the full error:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been stuck with this for days.

Comment: Are you using an external device or reading a video file?

Comment: Just a video file.

Comment: I assume the problem is Debian can't find the video using `[video_path]`. Did you debug, whether the video is available in the `[video_path]` or not?

Comment: Yeah, I checked a couple of time, compared the listed path with the one that's being called. Should be fine as far as I am concerned.